# Unable to locate libmagickwand-dev package with Unicorn restart on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicode, rmagick

I've installed the libmagickwand-dev package on Ubuntu 14.04 for rmagick and am getting the following error when restarting unicorn:

```
E: Unable to locate package libmagickwand-devCONFIGURED
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the libmagickcore-dev package. I suggest you run.

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
sudo apt-get update
```

And run bundle and then restart Unicorn.

## Correction

The libmagickwand-dev package should be installed with imagemagick package

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
sudo apt-get update
```

And run bundle and then restart Unicorn.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm still getting the same error though after trying that?

Comment: @EthanWilkins Try the corrected answer and let me know if it works!

Comment: okay then this is the last rabbit outta my hat `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand5 libmagickwand-dev libgmp-dev` Let me know if this works!

Comment: Haha thanks man, I really appreciate it but still no dice and I have absolutely no idea why. If it helps I never actually set up any user accounts on the server so I don't normally use sudo in this set up but I'm pretty sure using that might've been what caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: Let me just float my thought process here.. So this is happening because your rmagick  gem is missing a dependency package on the server because of which it fails thus failing unicorn to start in the process. All we have to do it figure out which is the missing dependency and install it on the server...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133600/discussion-between-aniket-rao-and-ethan-wilkins).